# How to generate a WCF Client from the WSDL only for certain endpoints?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf, soap

I have the WSDL of a large enterprise web service, which includes several endpoints, out of which I only intend to use one.

I tried generating the Service Client in Visual Studio by adding a Service Reference to the project. The issue is that due to the high number of endpoints available in the service, the generated client code in `Reference.cs` ended up having more than 1,400,000 lines, and Visual Studio seems to have a hard time handling it (IntelliSense often hangs, sometimes the whole VS crashes), and I imagine the build times will be longer too due to this.

And out of the hundreds of endpoints, I will only use one, and won't need the rest.
Is there a way to generate the Client code from the WSDL only for a certain endpoint, either with the Service Reference GUI of Visual Studio, or with `svcutil`? Or if not, is there some other straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: So far the only solution I could find was editing the WSDL manually, and delete all of the endpoints and data models I didn't need. This was a bit of a hassle, but it worked ok.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any way to generate a client for a certain endpoint from the WSDL file. But you can call the service of an endpoint individually through the channel factory.Here is the demo:

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService1111");

            BasicHttpBinding binding =new BasicHttpBinding();

            ChannelFactory<ICalculator> factory = new

                    ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(binding, address);

            ICalculator chanel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

You need to call that endpoint and pass in the address of that endpoint, define the corresponding binding, and then declare the channel factory. So you can call the method in the service. **By using the channel factory you can call any endpoint of a service.**

Comment: right, but where does the code for `ICalculator` comes from? Is that part of the code generated with svcutil or VS?